# Latex Font Warning While Writing Urdu

Tags: xetex, fontspec, arabic

I am trying to write urdu in latex but i am getting these warnings in latex

```
fontspec error: "font-not-found" The font "Scheherazade" cannot be found. For immediate help type H <return>.
fontspec error: "font-not-found" The font "Scheherazade" cannot be found. For immediate help type H <return>.
Font shape `EU1/ptm/m/n' undefined(Font) using `EU1/lmr/m/n' instead
\arabicfont\ is not defined!I will try to load Scheherazade (scaled 1.5)
Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

these are the errors which I am getting in Latex

this is my latex script

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
%\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic]{Nastaleeq Like}
\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Language=Urdu,Scale=1.5]{Amiri} 
\begin{document}
\begin{urdu}
مندرجہ ذیل مساوات کو حل کریں 
\end{urdu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you really get it with *exactly* this example, show the log-file. If your real document is different than show a real minimal example.

Comment: Adding `arabic` as a tag didn't quite feel right, but there is no `urdu` tag and the code says `Script=Arabic`, so it is hopefully not that bad...

Comment: your error message is from a document using koma script classes and incorrectly specifying a ptm font family, but you have posted an unrelated  document using article class and and latin modern family. So it is impossible to tell you what to change in the document with the error. The error is unrelated to the Urdu, it is just about the font used for the English in the  latin script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer for new example in the question:

[image]

Do not use the `times` package with xetex or luatex, use `fontspec` and a Times Roman clone such as `TeX Gyre Termes` The Urdu font usage works as you used it, although I also defined an `\arabicfont` to avoid a warning from the package.

Note you seem to have some old packages in your path that are using EU1 encoding fontspec has used TU encoding for Unicode fonts for some years so you may need to check if you need to update your system. (You have also shown warnings using TU encoding so you do not just have an old system, you seem to have a mixture)

I get teh above output from the code below in texlive 2019.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% not with xetex \usepackage{times}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
%\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic]{Nastaleeq Like}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Language=Urdu,Scale=1.5]{Amiri} 
\newfontfamily\urdufont[Script=Arabic,Language=Urdu,Scale=1.5]{Amiri} 
\begin{document}

Something in English

\begin{urdu}
مندرجہ ذیل مساوات کو حل کریں 
\end{urdu}
\end{document}
```

---

Original:

The document you post is unrelated to the font warning that you show.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
zzz
\end{document}
```

produces the warning that you show:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/ptm/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 3.
```

The `times` package, or directly setting the font family to `ptm` are intended for pdflatex and 8bit fonts, which are unsuitable for luatex, so instead do

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\begin{document}
zzz
\end{document}
```

To use an OpenType Times Roman clone.

Comment: How I can Write Urdu

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra as you showed in the question looked about right, you showed no errors or warnings related to Urdu. The only warnings you showed related to the English text but your question was so hard to understand as the log file you showed was not generated from the same document as you posted. You should edit your question so that the example document shows any problem that you want to ask about and the log file is generated by the example in the question.

Comment: I am editing my question

Comment: David Carlisle I have edited the question